# What is the proper way to Bind a WPF button click in VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, binding

I am trying to figure out how I should bind the click action of a button in vb.net for WPF

Here is a section of WPF code

**WPF:**

```
<TabItem Name="tab_emailSender>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=address}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=sendTestMessage}"
</TabItem>
```

**VB**

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim thisMessage as new Message

    Private Sub main() Handles Me.Loaded
        tab_emailSender.DataContext = thisMessage
    End Sub
End Class

Class Message
   Public Property address as string

   Public Sub sendTestMessage()
       msgbox("it worked!")
   End Sub
End Class
```

I am able to bind the textbox's text but I am not sure how to bind the button's click event to the sendTestMessage sub.

Comment: Where is ICommand object? check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni I am not quite sure how to make this work in my VB.net code but I am trying. Any other help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In order to handle the button's click event, if you want to follow MVVM, you need to create an [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.ICommand(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your ViewModel. [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.ICommand(v=vs.110).aspx) is the inteface, so you can do something like this (sorry for C#):

```
public class Message: ICommand
{
    public address { get; set; }


    public bool CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    public void Execute(Object parameter)
    {
        //Do the logic here.
    }
}
```

and the xaml (as far as your DataContext is the instance of Message type):

```
<Button Command="{Binding}" />
```

Of course you can implement the interface by yourself, on another class, etc. (I've made the implementation inside the Message class because its simplier here), but you can also find useful to use [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.50).aspx) or [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx). This classes will prevent you from re-implementing the interface involved every time you need the new command.

Comment: -1 I come here to find out how to do somethings in VB.net.  Question specifically asks for VB.net and the online converters do not always help.